# converting a string to an array of multiple digit numbers

Tags: arrays, swift, string, linked-list

I was trying to converting a string into an array of numbers. The string is from a linked list and I want to get the numbers in the string without accessing the actual nodes.

here is my code:

```
var list: LinkedList = LinkedList()
list.append(value: 1)
list.append(value: 80)
list.append(value: 3)
list.append(value: 7)

var numbers = list.description.compactMap{$0.wholeNumberValue}
```

it outputs :

```
[HEAD] 1 -> 80 -> 3 -> 7
[1, 8, 0, 3, 7]
```

I want it to outputs like this:

```
[1, 80, 3, 7]
```

But I have no idea how to do it

Comment: list? how you initialize the list ? please provide full information

Comment: We don't know how your LinkedList is implemented so this is hard to answer but it looks like `description` returns a `String` (conforms to `CustomStringConvertible`?) and this is definitely not the way to go if you want an array of values returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the numbers in your string, split it with `split(separator:)` and use `compactMap` with `Int()` to find those values which are integers:

```
let str = "[HEAD] 1 -> 80 -> 3 -> 7"

let arr = str.split(separator: " ").compactMap { Int($0) }
print(arr)
```

### Output

```
[1, 80, 3, 7]
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is impossible.

`list` is a String. So, after you append the numbers it looks like this:

```
"18037"
```

There is no way to know that it was originally made from `[1, 80, 3, 7]`. It could have been `[180, 37]` or `[18, 0, 37]`

You haven't explained why you want to do this, but I would suggest either

1. Not using a string to store the values. In your case, use an `Array<Int>`
2. If you have to use a string, use a delimiter between the values, so that you end up with `"1,80,3,7"` instead and then you can parse them. (see [components(separatedBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413214-components))

Your code does a compact map over each individual character (that's what `String.compactMap` does) and then uses `wholeNumberValue` on that single character.  You cannot parse multi-digit numbers this way.  Instead you should split the string based on a delimiter first and then parse the array of strings.

**EDIT** (after adding more info to the question): If you have a linked list and you want an array of numbers, you should not turn the linked list into a string first.

Instead, create the array directly by iterating the List.

If, for some reason, you need to parse description (like, it's an assignment and you have no choice), then see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74746771/3937

Comment: list is a linked lst and will output as a string like this: ` [HEAD] 1 -> 80 -> 3 -> 7 `

Comment: Ok, you added that information after I answered.  Will update

Answer (score 0):

Hello Use Only map function to convert Int array to String :----

```
var list = [Int]()

list.append(1)
list.append(80)
list.append(3)
list.append(7)

var numbersString = list.map { String($0) }
        
print(numbersString)

Output :--- ["1", "80", "3", "7"]
```